# How can i implement hasManyThrough on my db structure or any other solution?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a problem with eloquent relations.
There are three table:

Sellers : [id, name]
Products : [id, title, variety_type(nullable)]
Inventories : [id, sell_price, seller_id, color_id(nullable), size_id(nullable)]

Colors : [red, black, blue]
Sizes : [s, m, l, xl, xxl]

```
 
Sellers
Id         Name
------------------------
1          First Seller
2          Second Seller

Products
Id       Title          Variety Type
-------------------------------------
1        Product 1      color


Inventories
Id  Sell_price  Seller_id   color_id    size_id
---------------------------------------------------------
1   10000          1          1 
2   9800           1          2 
3   10200          1          3 
4   9900           2          1 
5   9800           2          2 
6   10000          2          3
```

In fact, each product has many sellers through inventories and if I’m not mistaken hasManyThrough relation in Laravel need inventory_id in sellers that in my database structure not exists.
Now I would like to get this result in database:

```
    id: 1,
    title: 'Product 1'
    sellers: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'First Seller',
            inventories: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    'Sell_price': 10000,
                    'color_id': 1
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    'Sell_price': 9800,
                    'color_id': 2
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    'Sell_price': 10200,
                    'color_id': 3
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Second Seller',
            inventories: [
                {
                    id: 4,
                    'Sell_price': 9900,
                    'color_id': 1
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    'Sell_price': 9800,
                    'color_id': 2
                },
                {
                    id: 6,
                    'Sell_price': 10000,
                    'color_id': 3
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Sounds fine. What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: I would like to get mentioned result. I tried to do it by Laravel query builder but I need the inventories be nested for each seller that I don't know how to do it. of course hasManyThrough relation can't do it for this problem or maybe i don't know how to do.